# Simple deterministic primality testing for small numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, primes

I am aware that there are a number of primality testing algorithms used in practice (Sieve of Eratosthenes, Fermat's test, Miller-Rabin, AKS, etc). However, they are either slow (e.g. sieve), probabalistic (Fermat and Miller-Rabin), or relatively difficult to implement (AKS).

What is the best deterministic solution to determine whether or not a number is prime?

Note that I am primarily (pun intended) interested in testing against numbers on the order of 32 (and maybe 64) bits. So a robust solution (applicable to larger numbers) is not necessary.

Comment: What language are you using? there might be an AKS implementation that already exist for it..

Comment: I can't use existing implementations. This is for use in competitions and such where I cannot use external code. I don't want to use AKS because it takes a long time to code/debug. I'm looking for something relatively simple to implement yet efficient.

Comment: If you are calling primality test often and don't care much about space+all you need is speed, I suggest you precompute all the prime from 0 - 2^64 put it in a big lookup table. Or if you care about speed and space, either do memoization and/or precompute like the first million prime or so.

For 32 bit there aren't that many of them http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml

Comment: @Piti: you can't precompute all primes to `2^64`. 32, yes.

Comment: Why do you exclude probabilistic algorithms?  They are fine except for mathematical proofs, because the error probability can easily be made smaller than the probability of miscalculation due to imperfect hardware.

Comment: @starblue: No it's not :P. I don't want to include probabalistic ones because the test data for programs are hand-crafted and will likely involve at least a few Carmichael numbers, etc.

Comment: There aren't any numbers that systematically defeat the Miller-Rabin test like Carmichael numbers defeat the Fermat test.

Comment: @starblue: Not necessarily systematically. But if I only test witnesses less than 7 for example, they could easily come up with an example where that is not sufficient to test for primality.

Comment: @tskuzzy: According to here: (http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/StandardPackages/NumberTheory/PrimeQ.html), the method of combining Rabin-Miller 2 + 3 and Lucas has no known counter-examples. Therefore, whoever is evaluating your test is not going to be able to pull a curve ball on you like that. So in some sense, Rabin-Miller and Lucas have a "distinct class" of pseudo-primes of which there is no known overlap. Carmichael numbers will be caught by the Lucas test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Up to `~2^30` you could brute force with trial-division.

Up to `3.4*10^14`, [Rabin-Miller with the first 7 primes has been proven to be deterministic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rabin-MillerStrongPseudoprimeTest.html).

Above that, you're on your own. There's no known sub-cubic deterministic algorithm.

**EDIT : I remembered this, but I didn't find the reference until now:**

http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-A.9.4

> PrimeQ first tests for divisibility using small primes, then uses the
>   Miller-Rabin strong pseudoprime test base 2 and base 3, and then uses
>   a Lucas test.
>
> As of 1997, this procedure is known to be correct only for `n < 10^16`,
>   and it is conceivable that for larger `n` it could claim a composite
>   number to be prime.

So if you implement Rabin-Miller and Lucas, **you're good up to 10^16**.

Comment: Trial division is not feasible in my case because the primality test will called many times and needs to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: @amit: But as the OP said, it's a nightmare to implement. And it is still slower than Rabin-Miller.

Comment: @tskuzzy: You can always lower the threshold. I just pulled `2^30` out of nowhere. But it's still the most efficient thing for less than say `10000`. But otherwise, Rabin-Miller is probably your only choice for determinism up to `3.4*10^14`.

Comment: @Mysticial: But I need to do the testing for numbers on the order of 2^32. Thank you for the reference to the performance of Miller-Rabin. That's exactly the kind of results I was looking for.

Comment: @Mysticial: My comment is regarding the statement: `There's no known algorithm to test them efficiently and deterministically`. It's wrong, because AKS [with it's disadvatages] does it.

Comment: @amit: I never defined "efficient". If "efficient" means polynomial. Then yes AKS is efficient. But if "efficient" is sub-cubic, then no AKS isn't.

Comment: the literature usually refers to "efficient" as polynomial, if you wish to refer "efficient" in a different way, you should explicitly mention what way it is.

Comment: @amit: Agreed, lemme fix my answer.

Comment: That 10^16 bound is good for about 53 bits. It seems like a good challenge to find the first number that fails this test.

Comment: @Mystical: "Rabin-Miller with the first 7 primes" is _obviously_ deterministic. What's non-trivial is that Rabin-Miller with the first 7 primes has been proven to be _correct_ up to the bound.

Answer (score 3):

If I didn't care about space, I would try precomputing all the primes below 2^32 (~4e9/ln(4e9)*4 bytes, which is less than 1GB), store them in the memory and use a binary search. You can also play with memory mapping of the file containing these precomputed primes (pros: faster program start, cons: will be slow until all the needed data is actually in the memory).

Answer (score 2):

If you can factor *n*-1 it is easy to prove that *n* is prime, using a method developed by Edouard Lucas in the 19th century. You can read about the algorithm at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test), or look at my implementation of the algorithm at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/02/02/proving-primality/). There are variants of the algorithm that require only a partial factorization.

If the factorization of *n*-1 is difficult, the best method is the [elliptic curve primality proving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality_proving) algorithm, but that requires more math, and more code, than you may be willing to write. That would be much faster than AKS, in any case.

Are you sure that you need an absolute proof of primality? The [Baillie-Wagstaff algorithm](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/01/26/primality-checking-revisited/) is faster than any deterministic primality prover, and there are no known counter-examples.

If you know that *n* will never exceed 2^64 then strong pseudo-prime tests using the [first twelve primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongPseudoprime.html) as bases are sufficient to prove *n* prime. For 32-bit integers, strong pseudo-prime tests to the three bases 2, 7 and 61 are sufficient to prove primality.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to pre-calculate as many primes as you have space for.  You can fit in a lot at one bit per number and halve the space by only sieving odd numbers (treating 2 as a special case).
2. For numbers from `Sieve.MAX_NUM` up to the square of `Sieve.MAX_NUM` you can use trial division because you already have the required primes listed. Judicious use of Miller-Rabin on larger unfactored residues can speed up the process a lot.
3. For numbers larger than that I would use one of the probabilistic tests, Miller-Rabin is good and if repeated a few times can give results that are less likely to be wrong than a hardware failure in the computer you are running.